# Asymptotics of number of possibilities that $V$ dice rolls add up to $n V$ for $V\to\infty$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

If we roll an $(s+1)$-sided dice $V$ times (assuming the sides are labelled by $0$, $1$ up to $s$) the number of possibilities to get exactly $N$ is well-known to be given by (see derivation [here](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/what-to-expect-when-throwing-dice-and-adding-them-up-5231f3831d7))
\begin{align}
d(V,N,s)=\sum_j (-1)^j\binom{V}{t}\binom{V+n-j(s+1)-1}{V-1}\,.
\end{align}
We also know that the resulting probability distribution
\begin{align}
p(V,N,s)=(s+1)^{-V}d(V,N,s)
\end{align}
approaches a normal distribution centered at $\mu=\frac{s V}{2}$ with standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{V s (2+s)}{12}}$.

However, I would like to find the asymptotics of $d(V,n V,s)$ as we take $V\to\infty$, where $n$ is a fixed fraction $n\in[0,s]$ and $s$ a fixed integer (of course!). I know that the Gaussian approximation is only exact right at the center $N=\frac{s V}{2}$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
d(V,\frac{sV}{2},s)\sim \sqrt{\frac{6}{s(2+s)\pi V}}\,e^{\log(1+s)V}\quad\text{as}\quad V\to\infty\,.
\end{align}
I'm struggling to compute the asymptotics for other choices of $n$, as I do not know how to deal with the sum. I expect a structure alike to
\begin{align}
d(V,nV,s)\sim \frac{\alpha(s,n)}{\sqrt{V}}\,e^{f(s,n) V}\quad\text{as}\quad V\to\infty\
\end{align}
with $f(s,\frac{s}{2})=\log(1+s)$, but I don't know how to find $f$ for other values of $n$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you don't trust the Gaussian approximation

Comment: Because I know that it is wrong (away from the Gaussian peak). One can see it explicitly for s=1, in which case $d(V,N,1)=\binom{V}{N}$. If one now expands this (using Sterling's formula) and compares it to the Gaussian approximation, one sees that the Gaussian is only correct at the peak.

Comment: I depends what you mean by "correct" (or "exactly right"). The Gaussian Is a fair (correct first order) approximation for large $V$ , as far as $N/V$ is not too far from the center - http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/NormalApprox.pdf

Comment: Yes, I want to get the asymptotics (i.e. the factor before V in the exponent in my list outline equation) to be exact. The Gaussian approximation is rather crude, as it essentially assumes that this factor is constant.

Comment: The result you want is called Cramer's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you very much. Could you explain this a little bit? I now figured out that my question amounts to understanding the asymptotics of the q-binomial coefficients and my current literature review seems to indicate that the asymptotics for the cases I'm interested in has not been fully shown (only certain partial results). Are you saying that Cramer's theorem showed the correct asymptotics? Do you have a reference where the function $f(s,n)$ that I'm looking for is shown?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but in L. Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics (1974) the following formula is provided:

$$ d(V,N,s) = \binom{V,s}{N}=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \left( \frac{\sin (s+1)\, \phi}{\sin \phi} \right)^V \cos [ (V s-2N) \phi ] \, d\phi$$

Edit: see also
[A Note on Extended Binomial Coefficients, Thorsten Neuschel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7429)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a look of I can extract some asymptotics from there!

Answer (score 1):

**Partial update:**

This is not a full solution, but based on the helpful comments I wanted to give an update. What I am looking for is clearly the asymptotic behavior of the extended binomial coefficients (also known as polynomial coefficients - not to be confused with the $q$-binomial coefficients). While the $q$-binomial coefficients usually have the $q$ as lower subscript, the extended binomial coefficients either have the $q$ separated by a comma or as superscript.

There appears to be a slight difference in convention, but I followed the convention where
$$ \sum^\infty_{k=0}\binom{n,q}{k}x^k=(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^q)^n.$$
There is also the convention where the sum only goes up to $x^{q-1}$, so everything in this case $q\to q+1$ (with respect to my convention).

The asymptotics of these coefficients has been studied, but to my knowledge the case considered by me has not been solved in generality (but rather only for $n=q/2$, which I had already found). Recent references include:

- [JIYOU LI: ASYMPTOTIC ESTIMATE FOR THE POLYNOMIAL COEFFICIENTS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1803.pdf)
- [Steffen Eger: Stirling's approximation for central extended binomial coefficients](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.2122)
- [Thorsten Neuschel: A Note on Extended Binomial Coefficients](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7429.pdf)

I'm still trying to figure out if the integral representation suggested by leonbloy provides some help, but using a Gaussian approximation only allowed me to rederive the result for $n=q/2$. As this concerns integration, I started this [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524470/asymptotics-of-function-times-increasingly-oscillating-cosine).

I also found an interesting reference in the appendix of [this book](https://academic.oup.com/book/43969/chapter/369349960), where the trinomial case ($s=2$) is solved. The relevant asymptotics is given in Theorem D.4 and the form of the function $f(n,s=2)$ is explained in Corollary D.6.

Comment: These are not the $q$-binomial coefficients.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? When I checked them, they matched. Just for definiteness:

Comment: They just aren't, and anyone calling these the $q$-binomial coefficients is using that term in a very nonstandard way. Here is the $q$-binomial theorem as usually understood: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem

Comment: Ah, great - found it. I corrected it now. What I'm referring to are the extended binomial coefficients or also polynomial coefficients. Depending on the conventions, they can also be called $(q+1)$-nomial coefficients. In particular, for $q=2$, they are known as trinomial coefficients. I got confused, because their notation is sometimes very similar (i.e., (q) as superscript).