# Asymptotics of function times increasingly oscillating cosine

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Based on a very helpful answer of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521960/asymptotics-of-number-of-possibilities-that-v-dice-rolls-add-up-to-n-v-for/4524370#4524370), I could convert a sum (whose asymptotics I'm interested in) into an integral. As this leads to a rather different question involving integrals, I decided to separate it here.

I would like to understand the asymptotics of the integral
$$ d(V,n,s) = \binom{V,s}{nV}=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  \left( \frac{\sin (s+1)\, \phi}{\sin \phi} \right)^V \cos [ V(s-2n) \phi ] \, d\phi \sim \frac{\alpha(s,n)}{\sqrt{V}}e^{f(s,n)V}\,\text{for}\,V\to\infty$$
where $n\in[0,s]$. If possible, I would like to find the exact form of $f(s,n)$ for now. $\alpha(s,n)$ would also be nice, but is less urgent.

Clearly, this is the product of a function with exponential growth
$$ I_1(\phi)=\left( \frac{\sin (s+1)\, \phi}{\sin \phi} \right)^V$$
whose maximum sits at $\phi=0$ with $I_1=(s+1)^V$ and a highly oscillating function
$$ I_2(\phi)=\cos [ V(s-2n) \phi ]\,.$$
We immediately see that the function is symmetric around $n=s/2$.

A first approximation could be to take $I_1(\phi)$ as a Gaussian $I_1\approx (s+1)^V e^{-\alpha \phi^2}$, where $\alpha$ can be computed from the second derivative $I''_1(\phi)$ to be $\alpha=\frac{s(s+2)V}{6}$. If we then use the well-known integration formula $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\alpha \phi^2}\cos{k\phi}d\phi=e^{-\frac{k^2}{4\alpha}}$, I find
$$ f(n,s)\approx\log (s+1)-\frac{3 (s-2 n)^2}{2 s (s+2)}\,.$$

This is exact at $n=s/2$, but not as we move away from it. In particular, I know that $f(n=0,s)=0$, which is not the case for above expression. I believe above formula corresponds to the Taylor series of $f(n,s)$ at $n=s/2$. However, I would like to find the exact expression...

From previous considerations, I happen to know the exact form for $s=1$, namely
$$ f(n,s=1)=-n \log(n)-(1-n)\log(1-n)\,.$$
I expect a similar form involving $n\log(n)$ and $(s-n)\log(s-n)$, but was not able to guess the correct one!

Comment: looks like gradient descent/laplace method is the way to go here.
hint: write $ (...)^V = e^{V \ln(...)}$ and $\cos(V(...)) = \Re e^{i V (...)}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. This approximation turns out to very similar to approximating $I_1(\phi)$ by a Gaussian and does not seem to capture the exact asymptotics. I found this reference (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03610910701790269?needAccess=true) claiming that they improve Laplace method, but it seems that it would still be only an approximation.